# How to make ArrayList of different types of objects?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have two pojo classes, viz `PostFeed` and `SessionFeed`

**PostFeed.class**

```
public class PostFeed implements Parcelable{

private int pid;
private int uid;
private String link;
private String title;
private String description;
private int up;
private int comment_count;
private String postPicUrl;
private Date dop;
private String user_name;
private String user_pic;
private String user_status;
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
//getters and setters
}
```

**SessionFeed.class**

```
public class SessionFeed implements Parcelable{
private String session_title;
private String session_image;
private String session_description;
private int session_id;
private String s_venue;
private String s_coordinator;
private String s_c_email;
private String s_c_phone;
private String resource_person;
private String rp_desg;
private String time_and_date;
private String address;
private String room;
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
private Date Dosp;
String user_name;
int uid;
String user_status;
String user_pic;
// getters and setters
}
```

I'm trying to create a search activity which searches the data from MySqlite database. There are two separate tables for each Types i.e. `PostFeedTable` and `SessionFeedTable` in two different Databases.

Inside my database operations class, this is what I'm returning:

```
 public ArrayList<PostFeed> readPostForSearch(String searchText, DatabaseOperations dop){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<PostFeed> newsFeedList = new ArrayList<>();
    String query ="select * from " + html_test_const.getTable_name() + " where " + html_test_const.getTitle() +" LIKE '%"+searchText+"%' OR "+ html_test_const.getDescription() + " LIKE '%"+searchText+"%'"+" order by date desc " +";";
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        L.m("loading entries " + cursor.getCount() + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        do {

            //create a new object and retrieve the data from the cursor to be stored in this object
            PostFeed postFeed = new PostFeed();
            postFeed.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getTitle())));
            postFeed.setLink(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getLink())));
            postFeed.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getDescription())));
            long dateOfPost = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getDate()));
            postFeed.setDop(new java.sql.Date(dateOfPost));
            postFeed.setUser_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getUser_name())));
            postFeed.setPid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getSr_key())));
            postFeed.setUp(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getUp_down())));
            postFeed.setComment_count(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getComment_count())));
            postFeed.setUid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getUid())));
            postFeed.setPostPicUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getPost_pic())));
            postFeed.setUser_pic(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getUser_pic())));
            postFeed.setUser_status(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(html_test_const.getUser_status())));
            newsFeedList.add(postFeed);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return newsFeedList;
}
```

This is same for session database operations with respective variables.

> SearchActivity contains a recycler view whose adapter takes an `ArrayList` and set that list, which further would contain two types of row elements.

**Question:** How to create an arraylist which contains these two types of Objects and further how to make recycler view show these two types of objects from the arraylist.

*If you need more clarification let me know. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: You can create a object c which contains both objects a and b. Then create an arraylist of c.

Comment: Sounds really easy, can you please help with code snippets? @nikka

Comment: Added an answer, please comment if you are able to use the same or not

Comment: please accept the correct answers. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @nikka , i'll definitely accept the answer when problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Feeds implements Parcelable{

private PostFeed postFeed;
private SessionFeed sessionFeed;

Public Feeds(PostFeed postfeed, SessionFeed sessionfeed){
this.postFeed = postfeed
this.sessionFeed = sessionfeed
}
}
```

And then array list of Feeds will solve the problem.

And

```
for(int i=0: i<postfeedArraylist.size; i ++)
    feedsArraylist.add( new Feeds(postfeedArraylist.get(i), null);
```

Repeat same for loop for sessionfeedArraylist as well.

Comment: What about database operations? How to access the stored data using above.
Primarily: I'm accessing my data from database.

Comment: Get two different arraylists of postfeed and sessionfeed then simply put them to feeds arraylist. So for each member of feeds either postfeed will be null of sessionfeed will be null.

Comment: just a note: it's impossible to have a either of the list null. Both of the arraylist are having some data, what to do now?

Comment: No you missinderstood. Lets say you got 3 postfeed and 2 sessionfeed. Feeds will have 5 members. In starting 2 sessionfeed will have values and postfeed object of feeds will be null and in last 3 members postfeed have values and sessionfeed will be null.

Comment: understood. I'll implement this and when done , accept your answer for sure, do you mind If i talk to you somewhere to seek help if stuck somewhere?

Comment: Then in adapter you need to put a check that if feed.sessionfeed is null go through postfeed layout and if feed.postfeed is null go through sessionfeed.

Comment: Add a comment I will reply to your problem regarding this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124141/discussion-between-asif-ali-and-nikka).

Answer (score 1):

As there doesn't appear to be much that's common between the two, despite sharing similar names, you may as well create a new object that holds a `PostFeed` and `SessionFeed`.

```
class FeedHolder implements Parcelable {

    private final List<PostFeed> postFeeds;
    private final List<SessionFeed> sessionFeeds;

    FeedHolder(@NonNull List<PostFeed> postFeeds,@NonNull List<SessionFeed> sessionFeeds) {
        this.postFeeds = postFeeds;
        this.sessionFeeds = sessionFeeds;
    }

    List<SessionFeed> getSessionFeeds() {
        return sessionFeeds;
    }

    List<PostFeed> getPostFeeds() {
        return postFeeds;
    }

    //If you're using this data in an adapter, knowing the total
    //size of both lists might be helpful.
    int getTotalFeedCount() {
        return postFeeds.size() + sessionFeeds.size();
    }

}

//...

List<SessionFeed> sessionFeeds = //whatever you do to populate your
//List of SessionFeeds...
List<PostFeed> postFeeds = //Same again.
FeedHolder feedHolder = FeedHolder(postFeeds, sessionFeeds);
```

Comment: What about database operations? How to access the stored data using above. Primarily: I'm accessing my data from database

Comment: I've made a couple of edits to this `FeedHolder` class that might be more relevant to your situation. Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what nikka is suggesting is correct. Improving on it, use the below class for your adapter

```
public class Feed implements Parcelable{

    private PostFeed postFeed;
    private SessionFeed sessionFeed;

    public Feed(PostFeed feed){
        this.postFeed = feed;
    }

    public Feed(SessionFeed feed){
        this.sessionFeed = feed;
    }

    //returns true for session feed type
    public boolean isSessionFeed(){
        return sessionFeed!=null;
    }

    public SessionFeed getSessionFeed(){
        return sessionFeed;
    }

    public PostFeed getPostFeed(){
        return postFeed;
    }

}
```

And in your database helper method, return list of Feed objects.

```
public List<Feed> readPostForSearch(String searchText, DatabaseOperations dop){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    List<Feed> newsFeedList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        L.m("loading entries " + cursor.getCount() + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        do {
            PostFeed postFeed = new PostFeed();

            ...

            newsFeedList.add(new Feed(postFeed));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return newsFeedList;
}
```

Repeat the same for sessionFeeds, and add this list from the database to your adapter's list. When setting the view check the type using `isSessionFeed()` and setup the views accordingly. Hope it helps.

Comment: if you really wanna help me, let's do the adpater? Help me in making adapter for multiple views. I can't do getItemViewType().

Comment: I have got my search results from database in an ArrayList<Feeds> , now how to setup things in adapter

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented `Parcelable interface` and hence you can create list of this `interface` which can be used for storing both `implemented class object`.

```
ArrayList<Parcelable> pList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: `pList.add((Parcelable) sessionFeed); pList.add((Parcelable) postFeed);`

Comment: I understand what you have just shown, but please go through the question , how do I perform database operations and finally get a list or array list which i send to my adapter. Please try to break down and elaborate more.